# How to assign a specific character depending on the class attribute

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The code below grabs some data in a url. My problem is I want to get and two specific span class and assign a character.

To indicate the results properly, I am looking for this:

`<span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>0.00% </span>` and give it a `+` like + 1.25%

`<span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>22.03% </span>`. and give it `-` like - 22.34%

Current Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/fomo-token/'

mainpage = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(mainpage.content, 'html.parser')
statsContainer = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "hide statsContainer"})
print (soup.pretiffy()) 


mcap = statsContainer[0].find_all("div", {"class" : "statsValue"})
mcapvalue = mcap[0].text.strip()
print("Market Cap: ", statsValue_marketcap)

mcapDilluted = statsValues[1].text.strip()
print("Diluted Market Cap: ", mcapDilluted)

statsValue_volume = statsValues[2].text.strip()
print("Volume 24H: ", statsValue_volume)

statsValue_volume_per_marketcap = statsValues[3].text.strip()
print("Circulating: ", statsValue_volume_per_marketcap)
```

Current Output: (Truncated)

```
#-- soup.pretiffy result (Truncated)
  <div class="statsItemRight">
    <div class="statsValue">$2,820,510</div>
    <span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 cYiHal" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:600">
      <span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>0.00% </span>
  </div>
  </div>
      <div class="statsItemRight">
        <div class="statsValue">$2,820,510</div>
        <span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 bQjSqS" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:600">
          <span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>21.31% </span>
      </div>
</div>



  <div class="statsItemRight">
    <div class="statsValue">$2,820,510</div>
    <span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 bQjSqS" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:600">
      <span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>21.31% </span>
  </div>


Market Cap        :  $2,820,510
Diluted Market Cap:  $2,820,510
Volume 24H        :  $264,758
Circulating       :  50,000,000,000 FOMO
```

Needed Output:

```
Market Cap        :  $2,820,510 (+ 0.00%)
Diluted Market Cap:  $2,820,510 (- 21.31%)
Volume 24H        :  $264,758   (- 85.92%)
Circulating       :  50,000,000,000 FOMO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below, I am assigning up/Down value based on the class, if class contains up we are adding "+" or else "-"

```
caret = "+" if "up" in spanChange.find_next("span")['class'][0] else "-"
```

Also i wasn't able to get the complete source code when using Beautiful soup so i have used Selenium with Undetected Chrome driver to get page source but since it works for you , you can replace it with soup instead
Full Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import undetected_chromedriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/fomo-token/'

chrome_options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
statsContainer = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "hide statsContainer"})

statsValues = statsContainer[0].find_all("div", {"class": "statsValue"})

mcapvalue = statsValues[0].text.strip()
spanChange = statsValues[0].find_next_sibling("span")
value = spanChange.text.strip()
caret = "+" if "up" in spanChange.find_next("span")['class'][0] else "-"

print(f"Market Cap        : {mcapvalue} ( {caret} {value} )")

mcapDilluted = statsValues[1].text.strip()
spanChange = statsValues[1].find_next_sibling("span")
value = spanChange.text.strip()
caret = "+" if "up" in spanChange.find_next("span")['class'][0] else "-"

print(f"Diluted Market Cap: {mcapDilluted} ( {caret} {value} )")

statsValue_volume = statsValues[2].text.strip()
spanChange = statsValues[2].find_next_sibling("span")
value = spanChange.text.strip()
caret = "+" if "up" in spanChange.find_next("span")['class'][0] else "-"

print(f"Volume 24H        : {statsValue_volume} ( {caret} {value} )")

statsValue_volume_per_marketcap = statsValues[3].text.strip()
print(f"Circulating       : {statsValue_volume_per_marketcap} ")
```

Should print

```
Market Cap        : $2,773,743 ( + 0.00% )
Diluted Market Cap: $2,773,743 (  - 1.08% )
Volume 24H        : $191,455 (  - 79.01% )
Circulating       : 50,000,000,000 FOMO
```

Comment: Is there any way not to use selenium?

Comment: If using requests works for you without selenium, you can continue using it. However, in my case, it didn't work because requests didn't retrieve the entire source code. This typically occurs when there is JavaScript on the page that renders elements during page load, which requests doesn't fetch.